# Submit button not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress

This form works, but not in Wordpress. I am new to Wordpress so I am not sure what to do. I created 4 files:

- page where I created the form
- contact.php
- validator.js
- contact.js

Here is the code for the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
                                <div class="messages"></div>

                                <div class="controls">

                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your full name*" required="required" data-error="Full name is required.">
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address*" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn modal-btn pull-right" value="send!" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Here is the code in contact.php:

```
<?php
// configure
$from = 'codedstyles.com <hello@codedstyles.com>'; 
$sendTo = 'Contact Form admin <sanlorena@yahoo.com>';
$subject = 'Hi! You have a new message from a lead';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email'); 
// array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Thank you! We will get in touch with you shortly.';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
// Send code
try
{
$emailText = "You have a message to respond\n=============================\n";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
   }
}

mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
$responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Comment: And how are you including the js-files? And "not working" is a bit fuzzy on the details. Doesn't it submit? Does it work without js? Do you get any console errors? Anything in apache/php logs?

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: everything on the form works but the submit button. I click and nothing happens. I have found out it has to do with adding php code in action, but I am just learning php so I don't know how to make this work...?                               <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">     And the contact.php file is in the root directory.

Comment: If you look at the Network tab of the developer tools in your browser and click on the submit button, does it generate a new request?

Comment: It generates 36 requests, the first 1 is to the contact.php The form works, just not in Wordpress. I need to find out what php code I need to add and where?

Answer (score 0):

```
action="contact.php"
```

I think the issue is the contact.php location it looks like it may not be finding the php file.

When dealing with WordPress you need to use the absolute path.

Depending on where you uploaded your php file, WordPress has a few functions that will get direct to a path such as WordPress root directory or a plugin directory or the theme directory.

```
<?php $path = get_home_path(); ?>  // root directory
<?php get_plugins( $plugin_folder ) ?> // plugin directory
<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?> // theme directory
```

If you need more information about these functions checkout the
[WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/)

Comment: The contact.php file is in the root directory, but how should I add the php code to action? I thought the following, but it doesn't work:                                               <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="<?php $path = get_home_path(); 'contact.php'?>" role="form">